# Can I customize Electron tray app?

Tags: css, electron

I'm trying to make my small app in a tray of OSX that will show some info.
The problem is that standard Menu lib allows me to create "natively" looking menus, when I want to make something that looks like this: (screenshot)

Is there a way to create some custom menu items with cells and images or should I create custom window giving the look I want using css? My biggest concern is translucency.

Now I just create it using tempate with *Menu.buildFromTemplate*. Mayb I'm doing it completely wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to create a custom window, you can't create custom menu items via the Electron Menu API.

Comment: So native custom menu items are only possible using Swift/ObjC/Cocoa?

Comment: You see, I tried to avoid creating menu with html/css, styling it to make it look «native». I's it possible to make it translucent/vibrant depending on dark/light theme using some third party libs?

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose you can use the following package to easily create a custom menu bar application: https://github.com/maxogden/menubar.
Just design your own index.html and custom logics and your are ready to go further.

Comment: comment from upper answer:

>>> You see, I tried to avoid creating menu with html/css, styling it to make it look «native». I's it possible to make it translucent/vibrant depending on dark/light theme using some third party libs?

Comment: Vibrancy is only available when you use html/CSS. In Electron nothing is really 'nati ve', because Electron wraps Web Applications into Desktop Apps. So if you want to avoid html and CSS, I would recommend to you to look into Native Mac App Development.